# Oracle SQL Developer - group by and count within specific date

Tags: sql, date, filter, group-by, count

SQL noob, trying to get some help grouping by unique name, providing a count, filtered for only start dates during 2021. This is what I have so far, and why I'm getting lost.

my_table:

```
| name     | start                           |
|----------|---------------------------------|
| Michigan | 01-JAN-21 01.00.00.000000000 AM |
| State    | 01-JAN-20 01.00.00.000000000 AM |
| State    | 01-JAN-21 01.00.00.000000000 AM |
| State    | 01-FEB-21 01.00.00.000000000 AM |
| Indiana  | 01-FEB-21 01.00.00.000000000 AM |
| Michigan | 01-FEB-21 01.00.00.000000000 AM |
| State    | 01-MAR-21 01.00.00.000000000 AM |
```

Trying to get count of the Name, filtered for only 2021 start dates. This is what I want my output to look like:

```
| name     | Count |
|----------|-------|
| Michigan | 2     |
| State    | 3     |
| Indiana  | 1     |
```

My code:

```
select name, count(name) from my_table
group by name, start
having start >= '01-JAN-21 01.00.00.000000000 AM'
```

But that duplicates the names (because of the unique start dates) and doesn't provide an aggregate count. I'm unable to remove the group by 'start', because that outputs an error in SQL. so I'm not sure how to get to what I want my output to look like. Would greatly appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Refer to this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6d0cd6f48815a09668c9bfc1915acec2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having is for filtering after grouping so that you cN filter based on aggregates, you can filter before grouping here,  so use where.

Remove Start from the group by, you need only name.

There is a function you can use to get the year from a date,
https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefyearfunc.html

```
Select name, count(name)
From my_table
where year(start) = 2021
Group by name
```

Or if start is a char or varchar then you can do

```
Select name, count(name)
From my_table
where substr(start, 8, 2) = '21'
Group by name
```

Comment: thank you for the fast response! i'm getting an error with the year(start) portion of the code: ORA-00904: "YEAR": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier" -- do I need to do a convert to datetime or something? I thought that wouldn't be necessary because it's already in ISO date format?

Comment: Yes, if start is a char field then convert it to a datetime. Or instead of using year, use substring to get the 8th-9th chars and check if they are '21'

Comment: Maybe you mean [EXTRACT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions059.htm) (rather than `year`) ?